# Do any real quantum measurements resemble this measurement model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurements, quantum-measurements

There's this simple model of measurement that I've seen in several books and papers (Peres's, Von Neumann's, Bell's, Bohm's, etc.). We have a system to be measured with coordinates $q,p$ and a measuring apparatus with coordinates $Q,P$. We are to measure some variable $A(q,p)$. The system to be measured has the Hamiltonian $H_0(q,p)$, the measuring apparatus has a Hamiltonian $H_1(Q,P)$. We assume that the measurement is performed at time $t=0$ in a very short time $\epsilon$ very forcefully, with very strong fields, for example. Thus we make the total Hamiltonian:
$$H(q,p,Q,P)=H_0(q,p)+H_1(Q,P)+g(t)A(q,p)P$$
Where $g(t)$ is zero except for the very short time right after $0<t<\epsilon$ and has integral $G=\int_0^\epsilon g(t)dt$. Bell uses $g(t)=G\delta(t)$ in one of his papers. Since the measurement is performed really fast and forcefully, we can ingonre time evolution due to the systems' individual Hamiltonians. Analysing it classically, immediately after measurement we have
$$Q(\epsilon)=Q_0+GA$$
And thus $q$ is measured. Quantum mechanically, the initial wavefunction $\Psi(q,Q)=\phi(q)\psi(Q)$ becomes
$$\Psi(q,Q)=\sum_A\phi_A(q)\psi(Q+GA)$$
Where $\phi_A(q)$ are eigenfunctions of the observable $A$. If the wavepackets $\psi(Q+GA)$ have little to no overlap, this can be considered a measurement of $A$.

This is a very ideal, easy to understand model of a measurement, but I'm not sure if it's actually realistic. Is there an actual, real life experiment that can be done in a similar manner to this model?

Comment: Resemble in what way? Are you asking if real measurements can be done so quickly that the non-interaction terms are negligible? Many real measurements are incredibly quick, if quantified by the timescale in which the measurement becomes practically irreversible, but a more realistic model would rely on the environment's kinetic term (analogous to $H_1$) to achieve that rapid irreversibility, like when the position of an interstellar atom is measured by scattering ambient CMB radiation. Or are you asking if more realistic models (like with time-independent Hamiltonians) have been studied?

Comment: If real measurements can be accurately modeled like this.